# Unit-testing COM written in .NET

Tags: .net, unit-testing, com

Is there a way to unit-test COM-visible .NET assemblies from .NET (not via direct .NET assembly reference)? When i add reference in my test project to the COM component whitten in .NET it complains.

Comment: You should probably add some detail about how exactly it "complains"

Answer (score 1):

There's always [vbunit](http://www.vbunit.com/). Unit testing vb code (vb classic / VB6) and com objects is what it does.